# Index array dimension as fraction of that dimension

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Is there any shorter way to do below?

```py
x[:, :x.shape[1]//2]
```

For `n`-th dim I'd need to fetch `.shape[n]` to specify indexing in terms of the size of that dimension. One could do

```py
n0, n1 = x.shape
x[:, :n1//2]
```

but that adds a line. The shorthand for `x[:, 5:x.shape[1]-2]` is `x[:, 5:-2]`, for example.

Comment: Hide the calculation in a function, and focus on getting the right value.  "short" is a bad criteria.

Comment: @hpaulj Having to look up a function for simple indexing unnecessarily harms readability.

Comment: The use of `x.shape` with `-2` occurs at lowlevel, in the compiled `__getitem__` method. Nothing in python or numpy syntax provides for fractional slices.  Maybe `np.split` will give ideas how work with fractions.  It's python code.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon: There are two different ways of parsing the “unnecessarily” in that sentence.  I think I know which one you meant, but it might be good to consider the implications of the other one: it’s not unnecessary if it expresses your intent and avoids extraneous variables with as little syntax as happens to be possible.

Comment: @DavisHerring I don't deny this _can be_ a good idea, just isn't for my purposes. I likewise figure what I seek may not be doable, but it's S.O., who knows.